# How to expand div height dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag which holds an image inside. The image dimension can go beyond the screen size. In such a case I wish to extend the div tags height and have footer after that. Currently i have styled the div tag as:

```
#dropbox {
    height: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 60vh;
}
#footer{
   display: flex;
   position: relative}
```

The problem is that the footer stays where it is. It does not go down all the way to the bottom once the image is displayed in the div tag.

Comment: Please provide full code. if your problem is with your footer ... where is footer css ... and your html

Comment: My bad. Added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed `height` on your div. If you remove it, the div should be pushing the footer down.

```
#dropbox {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 80%;
}
```